# Splitting a measure into a discrete and a continuous part

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal G$ be a $\sigma$ - Algebra over $X$, which contains all singletons $\{\omega\},\omega \in X$. I would like to show that you can split up a finite measure $\mu$ over the measurable space $(X,\mathcal G)$ into two parts $\mu_d$ and $\mu_c$, such that $$\mu = \mu_d + \mu_c$$
whereas $\mu_d$ is a discrete measure, i.e. there exists an $A\in \mathcal G$ with $\mu(A^C)=0$ and $\mu_c$ is a continuous measure, i.e for all $\omega \in X: \mu(\{\omega\}) = 0$.

I have already shown that the set $D$ of all atoms (singletons with positive measure) is countable. I have been given a hint, to observe $\mu(A\cap D)$ and $\mu(A\setminus D)$, but I do not really know how this would help. Any tips and solutions for this problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: For a set $A \in \mathcal{G}$, let $\mu_d(A)=\mu(A \cap D)$ and $\mu_c(A) = \mu(A \setminus D)$.

Comment: @angryavian oh... Well that made it surprisingly easy, thanks a lot!