# Decomposition of measure into continuous and discrete parts

Tags: measure-theory

In the proof of the theorem discussed here:
[Splitting a measure into a discrete and a continuous part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253748/splitting-a-measure-into-a-discrete-and-a-continuous-part), how do we know that the set $ D $ of all singletons with positive measure is countable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure is finite so for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ the set $D_n:=\{\omega\in X\mid \mu(\{\omega\})>\frac1{n}\}$ must be finite.

(An infinite $D_n$ leads to $\mu(D_n)=\infty$)

Then $D=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n$ must be countable.